# Using C++ namespaces in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a project that requires a third party library implemented in C++. I have successfully added library to my xcode project, but the problem is that the classes in library contains namespaces and when I try to access methods via namespaces, the XCode generates an error that: "utils undeclared". "utils" is the namespace I am trying to use.

My question is that is there a way to use C++ namespaces in ObjectiveC?

The code I am using to call the method is:
utils::method();

I have tried renaming my ObjectiveC ".m" file to ".mm" file, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Regarding 3rd party libraries, you might be okay with using static libraries (rather than dylibs).

Comment: @Daniel why wouldn't they like 3rd party libraries?  They're commonly used.

Comment: @Nektarios - I've heard of some submissions being rejected on the basis that a 3rd party library was used. It's hear say so I'm not sure it's true though

Comment: @Daniel as long as you're statically linking it's perfectly common and acceptable

Comment: Did you `#include "…"` the relevant header file?

Answer (score 5):

We are using C++ libraries in Objective-C and have no problem using C++ namespaces. As Mustafa has indicated, you need to change the Objective-C file extension to *.mm* to get XCode to recognize the file as Objective-C++. Then you just need to #include (not #import) the C++ headers containing the C++ namespace declarations - this is as you would normally do for 'normal' C++.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I am using XCode 3.2.6 - maybe you are using XCode 4 and it works differently in this?